# Do the mail() headers have to be terminated with a line break? (IncrediMail issue)

Tags: php, email, line-breaks

I'm using a function for sending UTF8 emails.
Since at least one recipient has issues with emails sent by my function (not UTF8, so special chars broken; some mail headers appear in body), I'm wondering if I have to put another line break at the end of the header string:

```
function mail_utf8($to, $subject = "(No subject)", $message = "", $header = "")
{
   $header_ = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n".'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8'."\r\n";
   $header_ .= "From: my@mail.com"; //Should be optional...
   if (!empty($header)) $header_ .= "\r\n".$header;
   $out = mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $header_);

   return $out;
}
```

So what's correct - `mail_utf8("x@y.z", "", "blah", "")` or `mail_utf8("x@y.z", "", "blah", "\r\n")`?

**Edit**: The obvious resource for that kind of matter - www.php.net/mail - uses such a line break only in example #4, unlike in #2.

**Edit2**: So here's the current version. See comments for further info.

```
function mail_utf8($to, $subject = "(No subject)", $message = "", $header = "")
{
$linebreak = PHP_EOL; //Seems to work everywhere, including IncrediMail
$linebreak = "\n"; //Debug
$header_ = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$linebreak.'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8'.$linebreak;
$header_ .= "From: my@mail.com".$linebreak;
if (!empty($header)) $header_ .= $header.$linebreak; //Last line break !?
$out = mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $header_);

return $out;
}
```

Comment: Well you're using neither in your code.

Comment: "*Some mail headers appear in body*" part makes me think that you might have *empty lines* in your headers, something like `"Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\nAnother-header: value"`. I would append `\r\n` to `From:` line and ensure that `$headers` argument does NOT start with `\r\n`.

Comment: @binaryLV: As I wrote below, it seems that IncrediMail (email client - NOT mail server) produces the first double line break after "MIME-Version: 1.0", which would explain why "Content-Type: ..." is the first body line (again, in IncrediMail only). But by using "\n" instead of "\r\n", I'm not standard compliant anymore, right?

Comment: (1) I still would suggest to move that one `"\r\n"` from `$header_ .= "\r\n".$header;` statement to `$header_ .= "From: my@mail.com";`, that would potentially save some headaches when removing setting `From:`. (2) As for not being standard compliant, it would be worth getting raw source of received messages in some way. It might be possible that your MTA indeed replaces `\r\n` with `\r\r\n` (as others stated), but some clients might be able to handle such cases. If you can get raw source of received message, you might check if there is `\r\n` or `\r\r\n`, when using `\r\n` in PHP.

Comment: @binaryLV: I've looked at the final email downloaded with Thunderbird with a hex editor. No matter if I set $linebreak (see Edit2 in first post)  to "\r\n" or "\n" - there are single CRLF's (13, 10) as breaks in the header - as it should be. In IncrediMail, this is only the case with "\n" (or PHP_EOL). With "\r\n" there is no CRCRLF (13, 13, 10), as you mentioned! But the last header line is "Content-Type: ", followed by an empty line (CRLFCRLF = 13, 10, 13, 10) and then "Content-type: text/plain..." (this is my header, note the lower case T). So does TB repair it or does IM break it?

Comment: I would write a simple POP3 client (if POP3 is used by those mail clients) by using PHP sockets to connect to mail server and download message without any other mail client. It's difficult to say what is being done with messages by mail clients.

Comment: Or, if you're too lazy to write a simple e-mail client, you might use some network sniffer (e.g., Wireshark) to see what's being sent/received by mail client. Would not work with crypted connections though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try terminating each header line with just `\n`, instead of `\r\n`.

> If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. Some poor
>   quality Unix mail transfer agents replace LF by CRLF automatically
>   (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). This should be a last
>   resort, as it does not comply with » [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822).

Source: [PHP `mail()` Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Okay this apparently solves the problem on the surface. The person who has the issues with my emails uses IncrediMail as client. I've checked it out and emails sent with my function (no terminating line break) and received with IncrediMail are broken - first body line is "Content-Type: ...". But with only "\n" as delimiter (still no line break at the end), IncrediMail displays the email correctly, except there are double line breaks where the user input (<textarea>) was a line break. So IncrediMail obviously replaces \n with \r\n (CRLF) and my function is not correct anymore... What now?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't pass a line break on top of header like you do on line 5, and try avoid alot of quotes, its look like confuse.

A re-factored exemple of your function:

```
  function mail_utf8($to, $subject = "(No subject)", $message = "", $header = "") {
    $header_  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $header_ .= "From: my@mail.com\r\n";
    if(!empty($header)) $header_ .= $header;
    $out = mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $header_);
    return $out;
  }
```

Comment: I would add `\r\n` to the `From:` line.

Comment: I do not use a line break on top of the final header. The difference between my code and yours is that my code does not put a line break at the end of the header that is passed to mail(). Your code will do that (if the $header argument is empty). The missing line break in my code is the original reason for my question.